# awk print between nth occurence of matching patterns

Tags: bash, awk

I am attempting to extract data between the nth occurrence of 2 patterns.

Pattern 1:  `CardDetail`

Pattern 2:  `]`

The input file, `input.txt` has thousands of lines that vary in what each line contains.  The lines I'm concerned with grabbing data from will always contain `CardDetail` somewhere in the line.  Finding the matching lines is easy enough using `awk`, but pulling the data between each match and placing it onto seperate lines each is where I'm falling short.

`input.txt` contains data about network gear and any attached/child devices.  It looks something like this:

```
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-5000, cardDetail=[CardDetail [baseCardId=router-5000NIC1, cardDescription=Router 5000 NIC, cardSerial=5000NIC1], CardDetail [baseCardId=router-5000NIC2, cardDescription=Router 5000 NIC, cardSerial=5000NIC2]], deviceSerial=5000PRIMARY, deviceDescription=Router 5000 Base Model]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-100, cardDetail=[CardDetail [baseCardId=router-100NIC1, cardDescription=Router 100 NIC, cardSerial=100NIC1], CardDetail [baseCardId=router-100NIC2, cardDescription=Router 100 NIC, cardSerial=100NIC2]], deviceSerial=100PRIMARY, deviceDescription=Router 100 Base Model]
```

*** UPDATE:  I forgot to mention in the initial post that I also need the device's PARENT serials (`deviceSerial`) listed with them as well.  ***

What I would like the `output.txt` to look like is something like this:

```
"router-5000NIC1","Router 5000 NIC","5000NIC1","5000PRIMARY"
"router-5000NIC2","Router 5000 NIC","5000NIC2","5000PRIMARY"
"router-100NIC1","Router 100 NIC","100NIC1","100PRIMARY"
"router-100NIC2","Router 100 NIC","100NIC2","100PRIMARY"
```

The number of occurrences of `CardDetail` on a single line could vary between 0 to hundreds depending on the device.  I need to be able to extract all of the data by field between each occurrence of `CardDetail` and the next occurrence of `]` and transport them to their own line in a CSV format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that uses regular expressions.  If there are minor variations in the text format, this will handle them.  Also this collects all the values in an array; you could then do further processing (sort values, remove duplicates, etc.) if you wish.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    i_result = 0
    DQUOTE = "\""
}

{
    line = $0
    for (;;)
    {
        i = match(line, /CardDetail \[ **([^]]*) *\]/, a)
        if (0 == i)
            break
        # a[1] has the text from the parentheses
        s = a[1]
        # replace from this: a, b, c   to this:  "a","b","c"
        gsub(/ *, */, "\",\"", s)
        s = DQUOTE s DQUOTE

        results[i_result++] = s
        line = substr(line, RSTART + RLENGTH - 1)
    }
}

END {
    for (i = 0; i < i_result; ++i)
        print results[i]
}
```

P.S. Just for fun I made a Python version.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import sys

DQUOTE = "\""

pat_card = re.compile("CardDetail \[ *([^]]*) *\]")
pat_comma = re.compile(" *, *")

results = []

def collect_cards(line, results):
    while True:
        m = re.search(pat_card, line)
        if not m:
            return
        len_matched = len(m.group(0))
        s = m.group(1)
        s = DQUOTE + re.sub(pat_comma, '","', s) + DQUOTE
        results.append(s)
        line = line[len_matched:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in sys.stdin:
        collect_cards(line, results)

    for card in results:
        print card
```

EDIT: Here's a new version that also looks for "deviceID" and puts the matched text as the first field.

In AWK you concatenate strings just by putting them next to each other in an expression; there is an implicit concatenation operator when two strings are side by side.  So this gets the deviceID text into a variable called s0, using concatenation to put double quotes around it; then later uses concatenation to put s0 at the start of the matched string.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    i_result = 0
    DQUOTE = "\""
    COMMA = ","
}

{
    line = $0
    for (;;)
    {
        i = match(line, /deviceID=([A-Za-z_0-9]*),/, a)
        s0 = DQUOTE a[1] DQUOTE
        i = match(line, /CardDetail \[ **([^]]*) *\]/, a)
        if (0 == i)
            break
        # a[1] has the text from the parentheses
        s = a[1]
        # replace from this: foo=a, bar=b, other=c   to this:  "a","b","c"
        gsub(/[A-Za-z_][^=,]*=/, "", s)
        # replace from this: a, b, c   to this:  "a","b","c"
        gsub(/ *, */, "\",\"", s)
        s = s0 COMMA DQUOTE s DQUOTE

        results[i_result++] = s
        line = substr(line, RSTART + RLENGTH - 1)
    }
}

END {
    for (i = 0; i < i_result; ++i)
        print results[i]
}
```

Comment: using the `awk` method you mentioned above, is there a way to also find another field on the same line (`deviceID="1234"`) and return that as the first field?  It seems like adding another `match` command and have it look for `deviceId` would work, but I can't get it to concatenate the results with the `CardDetail` results.  This `deviceId` field is outside of the original search parameters, meaning that it comes before the first `CardDetail` reference.  Thank you again for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have gawk or mawk available, you can do this by (mis)using the record and field splitting capabilities:

```
awk -v RS='CardDetail *\\[' -v FS='[=,]' -v OFS=',' -v q='"' '
  NR > 1 { sub("\\].*", ""); print q $2 q, q $4 q, q $6 q }'
```

Output:

```
"router-5000NIC1","Router 5000 NIC","5000NIC1"
"router-5000NIC2","Router 5000 NIC","5000NIC2"
"router-100NIC1","Router 100 NIC","100NIC1"
"router-100NIC2","Router 100 NIC","100NIC2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it sufficient?

```
$> grep -P -o "(?<=CardDetail).*?(?=\])" input.txt | grep -P -o "(?<=\=).*?(?=\,)"
router-5000NIC1
Router 5000 NIC
router-5000NIC2
Router 5000 NIC
router-100NIC1
Router 100 NIC
router-100NIC2
Router 100 NIC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 #awk -f myawk.sh temp.txt
 BEGIN { RS="CardDetail"; FS="[=,]"; OFS=","; print "Begin Processing "}
 $0 ~ /baseCardId/ {gsub("]","",$0);print $2, $4 , $6}
 END {print "Process Complete"}
```